# IB Python API - List of Prices of Stock for last x-seconds

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, interactive-brokers

I would like to get a list of prices for a given stock for the last x-seconds. I have written the following code to do this:

```
symbol = "DAI"
contract = Contract()
contract.symbol = symbol
contract.secType = 'STK'
contract.exchange = 'SMART'
contract.currency = "EUR"
contract.primaryExchange = "SMART"

class TestApp(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        self.data = []
        self.workingOrders = {}

    def nextValidId(self, orderId):
        self.nextOrderId = orderId
        self.start()

    def start(self):
        self.reqMarketDataType(3)
        self.reqMktData(1, contract, '', False, False, [])

    def tickPrice(self, reqId, tickType, price, attrib):
        if tickType == 2 and reqId == 1:
            self.checkLogic(price)

    def checkLogic(self, ask):
        prices = []
        seconds = []
        time_ = []
        seconds_counter = 0
        timer = str(format(datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=15), '%H:%M:%S'))
        while str(format(datetime.now(), '%H:%M:%S')) <= timer:
            self.data.append(ask)
            prices.append(ask)
            seconds.append(seconds_counter)
            time_.append(str(datetime.now(tz).time())[:8])
            time.sleep(1)
            seconds_counter += 1

        df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([time_, seconds, prices]),
                          columns=['Time', 'Seconds', 'Prices'])
        pd.DataFrame(df).to_csv("Prices/%s.csv" % symbol)

        self.disconnect()


def main():
    app = TestApp()
    app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 24)
    app.run()
```

This produces a list of the prices of the stock for the last 15 seconds. The problem is, that the price is the same for all 15 seconds, so it is not updating.
I guess the reason for this is that the price is just queried once and not updated in the while-loop.

How can I get the actual updated prices for every price query in the while-loop?

Comment: When I get repeated prices, it usually means that I'm trying to access data outside trading hours. What happens if you run the code without calling `self.reqMarketDataType(3)`?

Comment: According to IB's [documentation](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/market_data_type.html), delayed data is provided using special tick types (66-76).